# Show that $\log n $ is $O(\sqrt {n})$ and show that $2^n$ is $O(n!)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

These questions were just examples and exercises given in my lecture and I'm just using these for review. However, I'm quite stuck on these questions. The hint given to the first question was to use the fact $x < 2^{x}$ for all $x > 1 $ and $\sqrt{n} < 2^{\sqrt{n}}$.

For the first one I have,

If $x > 1 $

then using the fact,

$\sqrt{x} < 2^{\sqrt{x}}$

get the logarithm of both sides,

$\log\sqrt{x} < \sqrt{x}$

Then applying some logarithm rules, I get

$\frac {1}{2}\log x < \sqrt{x}$.

From here I am not sure if I implemented things correctly since the $\frac {1}{2}$ in the inequality does not seem right.

In the second question I considered that

$\ n!$ = $n(n-1)(n-2)... <= n  n n = n^n$

So if $x > 2 $ then,

$x^x > 2^x$

I am not quite sure if my solution for this one can also be valid.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Please share the context and purpose of this question.

Comment: "quite stuck" isn't very informative. Where are you stuck exactly? If you couldn't even write the first steps of the solution, reading the answers probably won't help you at all.

Comment: $$
\tfrac{1}{2}\log x \le \sqrt x  \Longrightarrow \log x \le 2\sqrt x  \Longrightarrow \log x = \mathcal{O}(\sqrt x )
$$ Where is the issue?

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: For the first, you are done: write it $\log(x) \leq 2\sqrt{x}$ and this is the definition of $\log(x) = \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$. For the second, you unfortunately go in the wrong direction. You want to show that $2^n$ is asymptotically bounded by $n!$, so you should aim at finding good upper bounds for $2^n$ or good lower bounds for $n!$. Here, try to lower bound $n!$ by a constant factor of $2^n$.